# AlertDialog on Google Maps for Multiple markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm having some issue with the following:
I have multiple markers on Google Maps. I've done this using a For loop that goes through an array of my objects and adds a marker for each of them. Markers show title and address. But now I need to make clickable InfoWindow (or just clickable Markers) which will display an AlertDialog containing additional information (description). But I can't get this to work. Alternatively, the data doesn't need to be displayed in an AlertDialog, I could also display it in a TextView.

Here's part of the code for displaying markers (this is a FragmentActivity):

```
...

Double longitude, latitude;
static LatLng coordinates;
GoogleMap supportMap;
String title, address;
BitmapDescriptor bdf;
ArrayList<GasStations> listGas = new ArrayList<GasStations>();

SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMap = fm.getMap();
...

if (listGas != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listGas.size(); i++) {
            longitude = listGas.get(i).getLongitude();
            latitude = listGas.get(i).getLatitude();
            naslov = listGas.get(i).getTitle();
            adresa = listGas.get(i).getAddress() + " "
                    + listGas.get(i).getLocation();
            koordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            supportMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(koordinate)
                    .title(title).snippet(address).icon(bdf));
            supportMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    coordinates, 10));
        }
    }
```

Markers show just fine and their InfoWindows display correct data. But now I want to display additional information based on which InfoWindow is clicked. If this can't be done via InfoWindow, can it be done by clicking on a particular marker?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Infowindow

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

    Map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {


        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file custom_window
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_window, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();


            TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lat);


            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lng);

            tvLat.setText("Lat:" + latLng.latitude);


            return v;

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'll try toying around with this and see if I can get it to display what I need.

Answer (score -1):

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
String add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();
            TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
            TextView loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.loc);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {           
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                if(addresses.size() > 0)
                add = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
            loc.setText(""+add);
            tvLat.setText("" + latLng.latitude);
            tvLng.setText(""+ latLng.longitude);

            return v;

        }
    });

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            googleMap.clear();

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(arg0);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            marker.showInfoWindow();

        }
    });

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
            new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Info Window Clicked@" + marker.getId(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();

 int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
 if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {       
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 else {      
  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 1);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

}

}